# How can i initiate an anonymous type without any value in c#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have one anonymous type which is an anonymous object of new {string a, string b}

```
var myObject = select new {
                   a = "a",
                   b = "b"
               }
```

I would like to initialize that object without having to input any info.

For eg.

```
Anonymouse{string, string} myObject = new Anonymous;
```

I am stuck on this and would like to receive some help.

Comment: You can't.  Anonymous types are generated by the compiler and are syntactic sugar.  Use `dynamic` if you want to do something like this.

Comment: @DavidL: You should wrap this idea in an answer, and provide a code sample. It would nicely augment Jesse's answer.

Comment: It seems you need `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan: A tuple rather.

Comment: `new { a = default(string), b = default(string) }` would have the same effect, I guess. Not sure what the point would be though, as others have said, the properties are read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types contain **read-only** properties. Therefore, if you want your object to contain properties, it is required to initialize your properties when you create them as they cannot be modified.

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Anonymous types contain one or more public read-only properties.

Think of an anonymous type as a way to save on typing of defining an entire class (syntactic sugar). If you create an anonymous type without putting any info into it like the following:

```
var myObject = new {}
```

Behind the scenes the compiler create the following type:

```
class __Anonymous
{
    public Anonymous() {}
    public override bool Equals(object o) { … }
    public override int GetHashCode() { … }
}
```

However, you cannot add properties later, which is why you need to initialize your properties when you create the anonymous type.

Comment: One could say that anonymous types with no values are completely useless.

Comment: While this is true, it also does not answer the question.  The OP is asking how to initialize an empty anonymous type, not how to change a property of an anonymous type.

Comment: @Abion47 Not so. It's useful if you're want static typing via generics. Yes, you could create a class for it, but sometimes that's overkill. For example: `var myObj = parsejson(jsonStr, new { name = default(string), age = default(int) });`, where `parsejson` is defined `T parsejson(string str, T templateObj)`

Comment: C'mon guys, both of your ideas are good, but they are addressing different parts of the question. Jesse's answer says that staying in the same terminology, there is no answer. David says that OP needs to learn a new concept. There is no better answer, it's just two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @JesseGood fair point, I extrapolated that.  I've updated my comment.

Comment: @Rob That's not an anonymous type with no values. That's an anonymous type with two values, i.e. `name` and `age`.

Comment: @Abion47 With two *properties*. Saying it has a value is debatable at best (doubly so if it was simply `name = default(string)` rather than including a value type).

Comment: @DavidL: I still think the OP does *not* want an empty anonymous type as they specified `Anonymouse{string, string} myObject` in the post showing two properties.

Comment: @Jesse: You may want to include link to docs with quote : `Anonymous types contain one or more public read-only properties.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx The key here is 1 or more. 0 is out of range, as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: @Rob Wrong terminology, my bad. I meant properties.

Comment: @Neolisk: It seems the other post proves the docs are wrong: `var myObject = new {};` :).

Comment: @Jesse: I think it's fair to quote MSDN, at least you say how it should work according to Microsoft. If that's not how they implemented, it needs to be resolved somewhere between their architects and developers. Make a ticket, find someone to blame, you know the process... :)

Comment: @Neolisk: The C# language specification shows how to implement it and it says: `anonymous-object-initializer: {   member-declarator-list**opt**   }`. Note the `opt` stating that the list is optional and can be empty.

Comment: @Jesse: Ok, the docs are inconsistent then. I still think it would be useful if you summarized our discussion in your answer, with proof links and quotes. That's why we have Stack Overflow answers anyway.

Comment: @Neolisk: I tried to give more explanation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JesseGood thanks for the explanation, I just created an object for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Anonymous types are generated by the compiler and are syntactic sugar. As a result, neither the structure of the anonymous type nor the property values of the anonymous type can be changed once created.

If you need to declare an empty dynamic structure and add properties at a later point, one possible alternative is to use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();
// at a later point
myObject.a = "a";
```

If you simply want to create an anonymous type without any properties, this is doable, by simply omitting properties during initialization.  However, you will not be able to change the structure at a later point:

```
var myObject = new {};
```

It ***is*** worth pointing out that similar syntax and functionality is proposed as an expansion for tuples in C#7.

```
var ll = new (double lat, double lng) { };
lat = 0; 
lng = 0;
```

or C#7 tuple deconstruction:

```
(var first, var middle, var last) = LookupName(id1);
```

Keep in mind that the [C#7 features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) are still in flux and may change before release.

Comment: What ?!! `var myObject = new {};` this actually works? Amazing... We are getting into JS land it seems.

Comment: @Neolisk absolutely.  It is simply syntactic sugar for the compiler.  The type is still generated by the compiler...it simply has no properties.  It is for all practical purposes identical to an empty class.

Comment: I'm mostly amazed by the fact it's there, supported by the compiler and yet practically useless. Developers rarely leave something like that in the language.

Comment: @Neolisk No more useless than `new object()` - but much more succinct

Comment: @Rob: I'll buy in when it becomes `var myObject = {};` like Javascript. Then add properties or functions using `myObject.property = something;` syntax. :) Then we'll have typescript for that (call it typesharp), and the circle repeats.

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous type with no declared properties is not possible, and even if it were, it would be useless, like Jesse's answer states. There is another type that might do what you want, however - a Tuple.

```
var value = new Tuple<string, string>();

// later...

value.Item1 = "a string";
value.Item2 = "another string";
```